# Draw route direction path on Google Map api v2

Tags: android, asynchronous, routes, google-maps-android-api-2, direction

I am trying to draw a bus route on my map by drawing direction routes between all the bus stops that the bus drives by.

I've got a list (markerPoints) with the LatLng objects for all the bus stops, and tries to run a loop for all points, where I for each point recieve a direction route between the bus stop at the current position of the loop and the next one.

The problem is that I sometimes get Nullpointerexeption error when running this code. It usually works the first time I run it, then crashes the next time. however, if I change the loop so that it only runs one time, and hence only get one direction route, it is working...

Could anyone help me find a solution for my problem, or point out what I am doing wrong?

**My Method with the loop calling the async mathods for receiving direction route**

```
public void DrawRoutePath(){
    //Start on "Torget" because of issues with route path in city center
    for (int i = 0; i < (markerPoints.size()-1); i++) { 
                LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(i);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(i+1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

                DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                task.execute(url);
    }
}
```

**These are my methods for getting directions async:**

```
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;      


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";         

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
 }



// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;        
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);            

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }       
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject; 
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                points.add(position);                       
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(5);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);                          
    }           
}
```

**Error log from logcat**

```
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at maps.z.ac.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at maps.z.bi.a(Unknown Source)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at maps.z.bi.b(Unknown Source)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at maps.z.ag.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IGoogleMapDelegate.java:137)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at com.mso.master.MyMapFragment$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MyMapFragment.java:469)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at com.mso.master.MyMapFragment$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MyMapFragment.java:1)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
04-22 20:03:18.911: E/AndroidRuntime(10471):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure you will receive a list of points to ``onPostExecute``? If ``result.size()`` is zero for some reason you're passing null to addPolyLine method.

Comment: If I change the for-loop to i.e.:
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { 
it is working perfectly. So I don't think that's the problem?
Also the code I've posted works some times, which is just really odd

Comment: You set ``lineOptions`` to null in the beginning of onPostExecute. If your loop does not iterate a single time ``lineOptions = new PolylineOptions()`` does not get called and you're passing null to ``addPolyLine``. Just saying.

Comment: it works! I changed the lineOptions to PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions(); instead of = null as you said, and after several tests the app is not crashing. Thank you!

Comment: You getting problem or not?